Energy range when deriving heat capacity in Sommerfeld model
In my textbook, they assume a scenario in which the thermal energy of electrons is $k_BT << E_F$ , then only electrons which are near the Fermi level could be excited due to external thermal energy. The energy range near Fermi level which include those electrons is $\Delta E \approx k_BT$.
I have some confusions regarding the information above:

Why should they examine samples that have low temperature, i.e low energy compare to Fermi energy?
Why the energy range in this problem is approximately $kT$? Why isn't it $k\Delta T$?
Why $\Delta E$ represent the energy range near the Fermi level? I mean, the expression itself is $kT$ and it has nothing to do with Fermi energy, its just thermal energy. So how can thermal energy of a material describe the energy range near its Fermi level?


kT is what is available in thermal equilibrium. Any electrons well below the Fermi energy have no place to be promoted to given the thermal distribution. Only electrons close to the Fermi energy can be thermally excited.
